# Problems about installing a gcc-6.* on CentOS-6.5

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc

Morning everyone, glade for your attention.

I am a newbie and got a problem when installing gcc-6 on my whole new centos-6.5 host which made me going crazy.

As you known, the default gcc version on CentOS-6.5 is 4.4.7 and not support c++11, so I tried to install a latest one.

After installing mpc-1.0.3, gmp-6.1.1, mpfr-3.1.4 and isl-1.6,  errors occur when installing gcc-6.2.

It shows:

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As reffered in this wiki page,[enter link description here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ), maybe I should check some depending libs.

Then I tried installing old-releases of mpc, mpfr, gmp and gcc instead over and over again, but the same error occured.

Also I checked the config.log, but no clue found.

So I post a thread here for any help. Appreciate !

For other things(i.e. commands, results and logs)which could be help are posted as follows:

**[root@192 objdir-gcc-6.2.0]# ../gcc-6.2.0/configure --prefix=/home/gcc-6.2.0 --disable-multilib --disable-libada --with-gmp=/usr/local --with-mpc=/usr/local --with-mpfr=/usr/local**

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libcilkrts support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libmpx support... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... no
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for the correct version of gmp.h... yes
checking for the correct version of mpfr.h... yes
checking for the correct version of mpc.h... yes
checking for the correct version of the gmp/mpfr/mpc libraries... yes
checking for isl 0.16, 0.15, or deprecated 0.14... yes
checking for isl 0.16 or 0.15... yes
The following languages will be built: c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
     gnattools gotools target-libada target-libgo target-liboffloadmic
    (Any other directories should still work fine.)
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG... bootstrap-debug
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison... bison
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for flex... flex
checking for flex... flex
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking for expect... no
checking for runtest... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for cc... cc
checking for c++... c++
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gcj... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking for gccgo... no
checking for ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... no
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for objcopy... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for readelf... no
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... host tool
checking where to find the target as... host tool
checking where to find the target cc... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... just compiled
checking where to find the target dlltool... host tool
checking where to find the target gcc... just compiled
checking where to find the target gcj... just compiled
checking where to find the target gfortran... just compiled
checking where to find the target gccgo... host tool
checking where to find the target ld... host tool
checking where to find the target lipo... host tool
checking where to find the target nm... host tool
checking where to find the target objcopy... host tool
checking where to find the target objdump... host tool
checking where to find the target ranlib... host tool
checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
checking where to find the target strip... host tool
checking where to find the target windres... host tool
checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

**[root@192 objdir-gcc-6.2.0]# make**

```
......
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0/gcc'
mkdir -p -- x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc
Checking multilib configuration for libgcc...
Configuring stage 1 in x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar... ar
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-lipo... lipo
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-nm... /root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0/./gcc/nm
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ranlib... ranlib
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-strip... strip
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc... /root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0/./gcc/xgcc -B/root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0/./gcc/ -B/home/gcc-6.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/gcc-6.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/gcc-6.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/gcc-6.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir-gcc-6.2.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**[root@192 objdir-gcc-6.2.0]# ll /usr/local/lib | grep -E 'gmp|mpc|mpfr|isl'**

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1297920 Sep  2 15:04 libgmp.a
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     913 Sep  2 15:04 libgmp.la
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 Sep  2 15:04 libgmp.so -> libgmp.so.10.3.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 Sep  2 15:04 libgmp.so.10 -> libgmp.so.10.3.1
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  529990 Sep  2 15:04 libgmp.so.10.3.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3460656 Sep  1 23:25 libisl.a
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     923 Sep  1 23:25 libisl.la
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 Sep  1 23:25 libisl.so -> libisl.so.15.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 Sep  1 23:25 libisl.so.15 -> libisl.so.15.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1968767 Sep  1 23:25 libisl.so.15.1.0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    3939 Sep  1 23:25 libisl.so.15.1.0-gdb.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  202398 Sep  3 13:56 libmpc.a
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     942 Sep  3 13:56 libmpc.la
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      15 Sep  3 13:56 libmpc.so -> libmpc.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      15 Sep  3 13:56 libmpc.so.2 -> libmpc.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   89669 Sep  3 13:56 libmpc.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      15 Sep  1 22:51 libmpc.so.3 -> libmpc.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  108035 Sep  1 22:51 libmpc.so.3.0.0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  931342 Sep  1 22:41 libmpfr.a
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     946 Sep  1 22:41 libmpfr.la
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 Sep  1 22:41 libmpfr.so -> libmpfr.so.4.1.4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 Sep  1 22:41 libmpfr.so.4 -> libmpfr.so.4.1.4
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  424265 Sep  1 22:41 libmpfr.so.4.1.4
```

**[root@192 objdir-gcc-6.2.0]# ll /usr/local/include | grep -E 'gmp|mpc|mpfr|isl''**

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 83934 Sep  2 15:04 gmp.h
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 Sep  1 23:25 isl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 13049 Sep  3 13:56 mpc.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  6236 Sep  1 22:41 mpf2mpfr.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 51307 Sep  1 22:41 mpfr.h
```

**[root@192 objdir-gcc-6.2.0]# vim config.log**

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../gcc-6.2.0/configure --prefix=/home/gcc-6.2.0 --disable-multilib --disable-libada --with-gmp=/usr/local --with-mpc=/usr/local --with-mpfr=/usr/local

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = 192.168.44.100
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /root/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2297: checking build system type
configure:2311: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2358: checking host system type
configure:2371: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2391: checking target system type
configure:2404: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2458: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2526: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2537: checking whether ln works
configure:2559: result: yes
configure:2563: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2567: result: yes
configure:2574: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2638: result: /bin/sed
configure:2647: checking for gawk
configure:2663: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2674: result: gawk
configure:3210: checking for libatomic support
configure:3220: result: yes
configure:3229: checking for libcilkrts support
configure:3239: result: yes
configure:3267: checking for libitm support
configure:3277: result: yes
configure:3286: checking for libsanitizer support
configure:3296: result: yes
configure:3305: checking for libvtv support
configure:3315: result: yes
configure:3325: checking for libmpx support
configure:3335: result: yes
configure:4118: checking for gcc
configure:4134: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4145: result: gcc
configure:4374: checking for C compiler version
configure:4383: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4394: $? = 0
configure:4383: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) 
configure:4394: $? = 0
configure:4383: gcc -V >&5
gcc: '-V' option must have argument
configure:4394: $? = 1
configure:4383: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: unrecognized option '-qversion'
gcc: no input files
configure:4394: $? = 1
configure:4414: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4436: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:4440: $? = 0
configure:4477: result: a.out
configure:4493: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4502: ./a.out
configure:4506: $? = 0
configure:4521: result: yes
configure:4528: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:4530: result: no
configure:4533: checking for suffix of executables
configure:4540: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:4544: $? = 0
configure:4566: result: 
configure:4572: checking for suffix of object files
configure:4594: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:4598: $? = 0
configure:4619: result: o
configure:4623: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:4642: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:4642: $? = 0
configure:4651: result: yes
configure:4660: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:4680: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:4680: $? = 0
configure:4721: result: yes
configure:4738: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:4802: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4802: $? = 0
configure:4815: result: none needed
configure:4893: checking for g++
configure:4909: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:4920: result: g++
configure:4947: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:4956: g++ --version >&5
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4967: $? = 0
configure:4956: g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) 
configure:4967: $? = 0
configure:4956: g++ -V >&5
g++: '-V' option must have argument
configure:4967: $? = 1
configure:4956: g++ -qversion >&5
g++: unrecognized option '-qversion'
g++: no input files
configure:4967: $? = 1
configure:4971: checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler
configure:4990: g++ -c   conftest.cpp >&5
configure:4990: $? = 0
configure:4999: result: yes
configure:5008: checking whether g++ accepts -g
configure:5028: g++ -c -g  conftest.cpp >&5
configure:5028: $? = 0
configure:5069: result: yes
configure:5118: checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
configure:5135: g++ -o conftest -g -O2   -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc conftest.cpp  >&5
g++: unrecognized option '-static-libstdc++'
conftest.cpp:11:2: error: #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
configure:5135: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #if (__GNUC__ < 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5)
| #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
| #endif
| int main() {}
configure:5139: result: no
configure:5200: checking for gnatbind
configure:5230: result: no
configure:5292: checking for gnatmake
configure:5322: result: no
configure:5341: checking whether compiler driver understands Ada
configure:5364: result: no
configure:5373: checking how to compare bootstrapped objects
configure:5398: result: cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
configure:5458: checking for objdir
configure:5473: result: .libs
configure:5647: checking for the correct version of gmp.h
configure:5667: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include   conftest.c >&5
configure:5667: $? = 0
configure:5685: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include   conftest.c >&5
configure:5685: $? = 0
configure:5686: result: yes
configure:5702: checking for the correct version of mpfr.h
configure:5720: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include   conftest.c >&5
configure:5720: $? = 0
configure:5737: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include   conftest.c >&5
configure:5737: $? = 0
configure:5738: result: yes
configure:5755: checking for the correct version of mpc.h
configure:5772: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include   conftest.c >&5
configure:5772: $? = 0
configure:5788: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include   conftest.c >&5
configure:5788: $? = 0
configure:5789: result: yes
configure:5807: checking for the correct version of the gmp/mpfr/mpc libraries
configure:5838: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include    conftest.c  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp >&5
configure:5838: $? = 0
configure:5839: result: yes
configure:6024: checking for isl 0.16, 0.15, or deprecated 0.14
configure:6037: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include     -lisl -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp conftest.c  -lisl -lgmp >&5
configure:6037: $? = 0
configure:6044: result: yes
configure:6052: checking for isl 0.16 or 0.15
configure:6065: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include     -lisl -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp conftest.c  -lisl -lgmp >&5
configure:6065: $? = 0
configure:6072: result: yes
...... (the rest omiited)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you installing a new CentOS 6 host in 2016?

Comment: Because it 's the same OS on which my company's server programs are running.

Answer (score 4):

**It's solved!**

For the final trying, I ran the **./contrib/download_prerequisites** script in the GCC source directory, rather than downloading, compiling and installing the depending libs manually, and it succeed!

By the way, the option **'-enable-language=c,c++'** should be added to filter java support when ran the 'configure' script, otherwise ,it still reported a error of 'libgmp.a: could not read symbols: Bad value' which is said to be about of java language support.

Thanks for attention.